# Symfony2, Can't display calendar of adesigns CalendarBundle

Tags: symfony, calendar, include, show, display

I'm trying to display the calendar of adesigns CalendarBundle

https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

I followed the "Installation" and "Usage" parts, but nothing shows up

```
    {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

    {% block title %}calendar{% endblock %}

    {% block body %}

    {% include 'ADesignsCalendarBundle::calendar.html.twig' %}

    {% endblock %}
```

I don't know what to do, do I have to write something in the controller? create a bundle?

Comment: Are any error messages shown on screen or logged?

Comment: Yes I found something in chrome logs : "calendar-settings.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: Routing is not defined" the line in the file " url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader')," I think it's related to jsroutingBundle needed to install CalendarBundle, I installed it.

Comment: And is JsRoutingBundle correctly installed? What is the output of `bin/console deboug:router`?

Comment: Indeed routing for jsrouting was missing in routing.xml but I still have the same error message.
I use an old symfony version
    php app/console router:debug
output:
    fos_js_routing_js         ANY    ANY    ANY  /js/routing.{_format}

Comment: Only that output? You should have routes referencing to CalendarBundle. Review bundle's installation steps... I guess it is not enabled or not added to `routing.yml`. Just as a curiosity: what is your Symfony version?

Answer (score 1):

It works now

I added:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important about this problem the position of the links must be in the layout.html.twig or in this example in base.html.twig.

In the documentation the calendar-bundle only say the requirement of installation FOSJsRouting but they not say configuration this links is obligatory:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

For this job I work with Symfony 3

Regards